# Why am I unable to send text through this Socket?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

This is the code for the Server I have:

```
public class XXServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4545);
        while (true) {
            Thread newThread = new Thread(new XXServerRunner(serverSocket.accept()));
            newThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

And I will have a separate thread for every accepted socket:

```
public class XXServerRunner implements Runnable {
    Socket socket;
    public XXServerRunner(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (true) {
                String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if(readLine!=null) {
                    System.out.println(readLine);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I run the Client:

```
public class XXClient {

    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter printWriter;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        XXClient xxClient = new XXClient();
        xxClient.setSocket(new Socket("localhost",4545));
        XXClientDataSender xxClientDataSender = new XXClientDataSender(xxClient);
        Thread xxClientDataSenderThread = new Thread(xxClientDataSender);
        xxClientDataSenderThread.start();
    }

    public PrintWriter getPrintWriter() {
        return printWriter;
    }

    public void setSocket(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    }

    public void sendText(String stringToBeSent) {
        printWriter.write(stringToBeSent);
        printWriter.flush();
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is also a separate thread for sending texts so I have this:

```
public class XXClientDataSender implements Runnable {
    XXClient xxClient;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public XXClientDataSender(XXClient xxClient) {
        this.xxClient = xxClient;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            String stringToBeSent = scanner.nextLine();
            xxClient.sendText(stringToBeSent);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens when I run my code is, I type text in the console and hit Enter a few times, and I see nothing in the console where I run the ServerSocket.. However, when I stop execution of the main method of the Client (that Java process I mean, when I kill the Java process for Client), in the console of the Server I see that all the text is now seen. Why is it so?

If what I am saying is not clear, it is like this:
Start Server
Start Client
Type some text, hit enter.. Nothing
Type some text, hit enter.. Nothing
Kill process for Client
All the text is now read by Server.

Why?

And I also I get this exception after I kill process for Client:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at XXClientDataSender.run(XXClientDataSender.java:20)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Because you have buffering when reading from the socket on the server?

Comment: @jcaron I do not think that is the reason. No matter how long text I send, it is still not seen.

Comment: Your server socket is going in an infinte loop because of `while (true)`

Comment: @faizal So that it can keep reading from the client socket. When I kill the client process, I see all the data sent.

Comment: @KorayTugay, did you send over 8K of text? The default buffer size is something like 4K or 8K...

Comment: @jcaron How can I decrease the buffer size to test if it is really because of the buffer size? I really do not think that is the reason but I want to make sure.

Comment: @KorayTugay, you use the other constructor for `BufferedReader`, which allows you to specify the buffer size as the second argument.

Comment: @jcaron I tried with size=2 and changed nothing.

Comment: Do you close `scanner` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Do the lines you send end in newlines? I'm not sure if printwriter adds them.

Comment: @PM77-1 Hi, closing the Scanner actually helped but it caused a different problem. In the while loop I had Scanner .. = new Scanner and then as last line scanner.close.. I was expecting that in the infitinite loop a new Scanner object would be created but the loop only works 1 time.

Comment: @KorayTugay - I was **not** suggesting you to close your Scanner object.  `Scanner(System.in)` once it's closed **cannot** be reopened later in the program.

Comment: @PM77-1 I tried putting a new Scanner.. as the first expression in the while loop found in XXClientDataSender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a newline character in your client code every time you send.

You're using `BufferedReader#readLine()` which expects a new line character or the end of stream.

Comment: Thanks, works.. Great answer. Why does it work when I kill the process?

Comment: @Koray Because the stream closes, the reader detects that and returns.

Comment: Thanks, and why am I getting this Exception: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found ?

Comment: @KorayTugay - I still think that if you run your server long enough you'll get [`StackOverflow` error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).

Comment: @Koray Because you have an infinite loop. Once you close the scanner, it has no more elements.

Comment: @PM77-1 Can you explain why? How can I fix it?

Comment: @KorayTugay It has been already mentioned that you have an **infinite** loop that creates objects (threads) that never go out of scope. JVM memory is not endless.

Comment: @PM77-1 Are you talking about while loop in XXServer ? That has a method that blocks the thread so until new Clients are connected, it is not doing anything, am I wrong?

Comment: @KorayTugay I do not see it.  May be I'm missing something.

Comment: @KorayTugay  - Missed that.